# Django Localhost not loading static files

Tags: python, django

I have a working app and have downloaded the relevant django files locally (via `git`) and am trying to run the app locally.  However, static files are not loading.

I receive the following console error when accessing, say, the home page (`http://localhost:8000/home/`) of the app:

`GET http://localhost:8000/static/imported_JS/jquery/jquery.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED`

or this error:

`http://localhost:8000/static/globe.png 404 (NOT FOUND)`

In my `settings.py` file, I can confirm:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),'..'))  # i.e. location of settings.py file
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn/')
```

I can also confirm there is indeed a `static_cdn/` file directory and it does contain the relevant static files.

The live `dev` and `prod` versions of the app work (which are hosted on separate web servers) but, for whatever reason, when running the app locally, static files are not served.

Any ideas on how to have the localhost server static files?  Most of the answers on SO regarding this type of question relate to mistakes with setting up `STATIC_URL` vs. `STATIC_ROOT` but these appear to be correct (at least on `dev` and `prod`).

Let me know if you require more info.  Thank you.

### UPDATE

Well, I struggled with this problem for an hour or so, and 5mins after posting this SO question, I think I found a solution.

Changing from this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = []

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn/')
```

to this made the difference:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn/')  # add STATIC_ROOT to DIRS
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn/')
```

I'm not sure why this works but I'll indicate your response as Answer if you explain why.  Thanks.

Comment: did you add in urls [serving-static-files-during-development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)

Comment: @BearBrown, yup indeed:  `if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Comment: Okay what I don't get is why we have to go through all this trouble? I thought if we use 'STATIC_URL` we don't need to manually serve the files? Is it not supposed to be simple?